# как избавиться от кнопок сохранить/отменить при фотографировании из приложения

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera

сразу оговорюсь,что пишу на xamarin(это не моя прихоть,а требование), однако в коде очень много общего java.Суть проблемы заключается в следующем, после совершения фото(камера вызывается из приложения) необходимо нажимать кнопку Сохранить(ну или Отменить), можно ли как-то избавиться от этого?т.е. чтобы после нажатия на кнопку фотографирования(совершения операции фотографирования) фото сохранялось СРАЗУ же и тут же возвращало управление приложению?

Comment: Можно только если вы будете делать фотографию не при помощи стороннего приложения "Камера", а сами.

Comment: @metalurgus , а есть ссылочки или пример кода, как это реализовать?